# Merging a Shallow and a Deep Functional Keras CNNs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I will phrase my question in a broad manner so that others might benefit from it as well.
I have a deep functional keras model (it isn't a sequential model, it's important to notice!), which you can see in the image as the orange thing.
I also have a more shallow functional keras model, which emulates some of the last layers of the backbone model, but with my finetuned weights, and an additional output layer that is not in the backbone model. You can see it in the image as the smaller blue thing, and notice the additional layer beneath it.

What I want is to merge the backbone model with the head model, so that i have all the layers of the backbone model, together with all the layers of the head model, including the additional layer in the head model, and the weights of the headmodel.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
model_input = keras.Input(...)
x = backbone_model(x)
model_output = head_model(x)
new_model = keras.models.Model(model_input, model_output)
```

However, when I will call `model.summary()` the backbone model will appear as a layer, and I need the specific layers to remain (since I'm performing a GradCam afterwards).

I would love to hear some advice as to how to merge these layers and remain with all the different layers in the backbone model.
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

give these two models (I use Dense layer but with CNN is the same):

```
inp1 = Input((10,))
x1 = Dense(512)(inp1)
x1 = Dense(256)(x1)
x1 = Dense(128)(x1)
backbone_model = Model(inp1, x1)

inp2 = Input((128,))
x2 = Dense(64)(inp2)
x2 = Dense(32)(x2)
head_model = Model(inp2, x2)
```

you can merge them is this way:

```
x = head_model(backbone_model.output)
new_model = Model(backbone_model.input, x)
new_model.summary()
```

the summary results in:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 512)               5632      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
model_4 (Model)              (None, 32)                10336
```

the layers of the head_model put inside the new_model are accessible through:

```
new_model.layers[-1].layers
```